# Find missing value from ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, pojo

I have a problem where the values from ArrayList is missing. When I toast `listCartItemValues.toString()` , the results are correct in accordance with existing data. But when I set `listCartItemValues` in Model DataItemCart then I toast, one of the values is missing, that's Starlight.

My API :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "cart_item_values": [
                {
                    "attribute_name": "color",
                    "attribute_value": "Starlight"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_name": "size",
                    "attribute_value": "XL"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "cart_item_values": [
                {
                    "attribute_name": "size",
                    "attribute_value": "10"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

My Code for getting `cart_item_values` :

```
private List<CartItemValuesItem> listCartItemValues;

for (int a = 0; a < data.length(); a++) {

    JSONObject dataJSONObject = data.getJSONObject(a);

    final DataItemCart dataItemCart = new DataItemCart();
    final CartItemValuesItem cartItemValuesItem = new CartItemValuesItem();

    JSONArray arrayCartItemValues = dataJSONObject.optJSONArray("cart_item_values");

    for (int b = 0; b < arrayCartItemValues.length(); b++) {
        JSONObject cartItemJsonObject = arrayCartItemValues.optJSONObject(b);
        listCartItemValues = new ArrayList<>();

        cartItemValuesItem.setAttributeName(cartItemJsonObject.getString("attribute_name"));
        cartItemValuesItem.setAttributeValue(cartItemJsonObject.getString("attribute_value"));
        listCartItemValues.add(cartItemValuesItem);

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "value : "+ listCartItemValues.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // this list contain Starlight, XL, and 10
    }

    dataItemCart.setCartItemValues(listCartItemValues);

    Toast.makeText(mContext, "data : "+ dataItemCart.getCartItemValues.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // but this list contain XL and 10. Starlight is missing
}
```

How to find missing value from ArrayList and input a missing value into `dataItemCart.setCartItemValues` ?

Comment: Why not converting json to map, and then perform operations?

Answer (score 0):

Move **"final DataItemCart dataItemCart = new DataItemCart();"** outside of first For Loop.

Move **"listCartItemValues = new ArrayList<>();"** outside of second For Loop.

Here is modifed code.

```
private List<CartItemValuesItem> listCartItemValues;
    final DataItemCart dataItemCart = new DataItemCart();
    for (int a = 0; a < data.length(); a++) {

        JSONObject dataJSONObject = data.getJSONObject(a);

        final CartItemValuesItem cartItemValuesItem = new CartItemValuesItem();

        JSONArray arrayCartItemValues = dataJSONObject.optJSONArray("cart_item_values");
        listCartItemValues = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int b = 0; b < arrayCartItemValues.length(); b++) {
            JSONObject cartItemJsonObject = arrayCartItemValues.optJSONObject(b);
            cartItemValuesItem.setAttributeName(cartItemJsonObject.getString("attribute_name"));
            cartItemValuesItem.setAttributeValue(cartItemJsonObject.getString("attribute_value"));
            listCartItemValues.add(cartItemValuesItem);

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "value : "+ listCartItemValues.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // this list contain Starlight, XL, and 10
        }

        dataItemCart.setCartItemValues(listCartItemValues);

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "data : "+ dataItemCart.getCartItemValues.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // but this list contain XL and 10. Starlight is missing
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your code is not working for me. I toast `dataItemCart.getCartItemValues` only get 10. Starlight and XL is missing